# Суффиксы целочисленных типов

Tags: c#

Есть ли объяснение почему для каких то типов есть суффиксы, а для каких то нет.

А если есть, то 2 минимум, а у `ulong` их даже 8

```
// Целочисленные литералы

// Тип byte
var byteVariable = (byte)1;

// Тип sbyte
var sbyteVariable = (sbyte)1;

// Тип short
var shortVariable = (short)1;

// Тип ushort
var ushortVariable = (ushort)1;

// Тип int
var intVariable1 = 1;               // По умолчанию
var intVariable2 = (int)1;          // Приведение избытачно

// Тип uint
var uintVariable1 = 1U;
var uintVariable2 = 1u;
var uintVariable3 = (uint)1;


// Тип long
var longVariable1 = 1L;
var longVariable2 = 1l;
var longVariable3 = (long)1;

// Тип ulong
var ulongVariable1 = 1UL;
var ulongVariable2 = 1Ul;
var ulongVariable3 = 1uL;
var ulongVariable4 = 1ul;
var ulongVariable5 = 1LU;
var ulongVariable6 = 1Lu;
var ulongVariable7 = 1lU;
var ulongVariable8 = 1lu;
var ulongVariable9 = (ulong)1;

// Вещественные литералы

// Тип float
var floatVariavle1 = 1.0F;
var floatVariavle2 = 1.0f;
var floatVariavle3 = (float)1.0;

// Тип double
var doubleVariavle1 = 1.0;          // По умолчанию
var doubleVariavle2 = 1.0D;
var doubleVariavle3 = 1.0d;
var doubleVariavle4 = (double)1.0;  // Приведение не избытачно ???

// Тип decimal
var decimalVariable1 = 1.0M;
var decimalVariable2 = 1.0m;
var decimalVariable3 = (decimal)1.0;
```

Comment: Все вещественные литералы рассматриваются как значения типа double. И чтобы указать, что дробное число представляет тип float/decimal, необходимо к литералу добавлять суффикс. Подобным образом все целочисленные литералы рассматриваются как значения типа int. Чтобы явным образом указать, что целочисленный литерал представляет значение иного типа, надо использовать суффикс. Суффиксы не зависят от регистра, потому можно указать хоть UL, хоть ul, это будет тот-же суффикс. Думаю сделано это для чисто ради удобства.

Comment: Суффиксы применяются не к _типам_, а к _литералам_: [Integer literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals), [Real literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals). / Суффикс регистронезависимый, поэтому получается минимум два. / Зачем он нужен? Чтобы различать литералы разных типов.

Comment: На счёт типов данных в скобочках. Это не суффикс, это называется явное преобразование данных. Преобразования могут быть сужающие (narrowing) и расширяющие (widening). Расширяющие преобразования расширяют размер объекта в памяти. В случае с расширяющими преобразованиями компилятор за нас выполнял все преобразования данных, то есть преобразования были неявными (implicit conversion). При явных преобразованиях (explicit conversion) мы сами должны применить операцию преобразования.

Comment: Про регистр зависимость спасибо! А что на счёт вопроса, почему некоторые литералы, нельзя с помощью суффикса определить ? Явного приведения вопрос не касался, просто использовал все способы обозначить литерал тем типом, которым хочу его видеть.

Comment: Всегда есть что-то, принятое по умолчанию. Вот в C# приняли, что литерал `1` - это тип `int` по умолчанию, без всякого суффикса. Литерал `1.0` - это тип `double` по умолчанию. А для других типов приходится добавлять суффиксы (или каст).